# How to deserialize Json to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a json array as ahown below with two keys "entities" and "TotalResults". within entities there is "Fields". I want to obtain the elements within "Fields" i.e, "name" and "values". so that i can iterate over the **Fields** to find the matching **name** and it's respective **value**. I have tried most of the solutions out there, nothing seems to give the result i want. Any help would be admired.

below is the Json array :

```
{"entities": [
 {
"Fields": [
  {
    "Name": "test-id",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "268"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "os-config",
    "values": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "pc-mobile-host",
    "values": [
      {}
    ]
  }
  }
  ],
  "TotalResults": 2}
```

Code i tried are below (only two are mentioned though i tried lots of other methods) :

1.

```
Dictionary<string,object> Result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
```

2.

```
  public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty("values")]
        public IList<object> values { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public IList<Fields> Fields { get; set; }
    }
    var Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't properly formatted, please fix it

Comment: Hi Anikhouski, Fixed it

Comment: If your json is manually edited, you can greatly simplify the problem by simplifying the json. Json that has unneeded arrays `[`, `]`, appears to be a common mistake. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77165172/19497610

Answer (score 0):

First (using Newtonsoft.Json) parse json to JObject and then you can access and iterate Fields objects using `SelectToken`.


There was still error in your JSON while writing this answer so I've modified it to be valid

```
var json = @"{""entities"":[{""Fields"":[{""Name"":""test-id"",""values"":[{""value"":""268""}]},{""Name"":""os-config"",""values"":[{}]},{""Name"":""pc-mobile-host"",""values"":[{}]}]}],""TotalResults"":2}";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var fields = jObject.SelectToken("$..Fields").ToList();

foreach (var field in fields)
{

}
```