# C# - Deserialize array of JSON objects into Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, system.text.json

```
 {
   "TestObjects": [
     {"the": "goal"},
     {"is": "to"},
     {"deserialize": "this"},
     {"simple": "array"},
     {"of": "objects"},
     {"into": "a"},
     {"C#": "Dictionary"}
    ]
}
```

Using .NET System.Text.Json. Seeking methodology to deserialize an array of objects where each object has two strings, as shown above, into a Dictionary<string, string>.

I have seen answers that describe deserializing into `Dictionary<string, string>[]` whereby each object is placed in a distinct `Dictionary<string, string>`, and that works. E.g. Ten objects results in an array of ten dictionaries. Example below works:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] TestObjects { get; set; }
}

var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test\test.json");

TestClass result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(stream);
```

So, referring to the above example that works, the goal is to deserialize into a C# property of the form
`Dictionary<string, string> TestObjects { get; set; }` as opposed to
`Dictionary<string, string>[] TestObjects { get; set; }`

Thank You

**Update - Answer**
Received several workable and useful answers. I used the answer by Sonny N that involved simply changing the JSON data format so that it would deserialize directly into a dictionary:

```
{
  "TestObjects": {
    "the": "goal",
    "is": "to",
    "convert": "this",
    "simple": "array",
    "of": "objects",
    "into": "a",
    "C#": "Dictionary"
  }
}
```

Sometimes with questions like this, those who answer have no way of knowing whether the JSON format is editable, as in some cases it may be received via network etc., and must be deserialized as is. In my case, the format is manually edited and is flexible, so I was able to use the better format. However, the other excellent answers are applicable to cases where the incoming JSON format isn't flexible.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert an array to  a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = JsonDocument.Parse(json)
            .RootElement.GetProperty("SimpleArray").EnumerateArray()
            .ToDictionary(x => x.EnumerateObject().FirstOrDefault().Name,
                        x => x.EnumerateObject().FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString());
```

But remember the dictionary shoud have the unique keys, otherwise you will get an exception

or if you want to deserialize to a class, you will need to write a json converter

```
TestClass result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(json);

public class ToDictConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    public override Dictionary<string, string> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray) return dict;
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                {
                    string propName = reader.GetString();
                    if (reader.Read()) dict.Add(propName, reader.GetString());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<string, string> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{

[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(ToDictConverter))]
public Dictionary<string, string> SimpleArray { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps a particular structure of JSON deserializes directly into a Dictionary<string, string>? Thanks also for additional detail on the token types. I stepped through with debugger and saw the token type state for each Read() step, so I have a clear picture of the flow now. Thanks to Jimi and you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to deserialize as a Dictionary, it would have to be in this format:

```
{
  "TestObjects": {
    "the": "goal",
    "is": "to",
    "convert": "this",
    "simple": "array",
    "of": "objects",
    "into": "a",
    "C#": "Dictionary"
  }
}
```

You could, however, add another read-only property that converts the array of dictionaries into one dictionary.

```
public class TestClass1
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] TestObjects { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> TestObjectsDict
    {
        get
        {
            return TestObjects.Select(x => x.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Helpful conversion technique in general! I see the distinction between my JSON format and the one that you show here. Perfect! I tested and it serializes directly to dictionary. I implemented a converter and that worked well so having the knowledge of how to use converters is very helpful. I decided to use your methodology, once I noticed that your JSON format is different from mine, as that is simplest for my current problem. Wonderful answers from all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple converter.

Decorate the Property with `[JsonConverter(...)]`:

```
public class TestClass2 {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectsToDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> TestObjects { get; set; }
}
```

The custom converter reads each property and value from the array of objects and uses them as the Key and Value of a Dictionary.
It's assumed that all *keys* (Properties) have a different name.

When the `Utf8JsonReader` gets to the end of the arrays, i.e., when `[Utf8JsonReader].TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray`, return the Dictionary:

Note: there's no real error checking here. I leave it to you, since you know what the real JSON contains.

```
class ObjectsToDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<string, string>> {
    public override Dictionary<string, string> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray) {
            throw new JsonException($"Array of objects expected. Got {reader.TokenType}");
        }

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray) break;

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject) {
                reader.Read();
                string key = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                string value = reader.GetString();
                dict.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<string, string> value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using your methodology (converter).

Comment: I see you have a deleted comment that mentioned `IJsonTypeInfoResolver`, so a derived `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` probably. If what's in the post is actually the JSON model you have, a simple converter is probably not a bad choice, IMO, it's easy to handle

Comment: The resolver appeared to be more of a utility for simple cases, so I didn't want to add confusion to the discussion. I implemented a converter, and it works well. Great!